# Discord bot (py) Dont't reply to messages on any servers but reply to direct dms

Tags: python, discord

**Discord bot (py) Dont't reply to messages on any servers but reply to direct dms**

I build a discord Bot with python using discord.py an as I write the (example $hello), it reply only on private dms not on any servers messages. I olready gived the bot admin on the server but still not doing anything.

My py code is:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

async def on_message(message): 
     if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
           print(message.content)
           await message.channel.send('Hello')

client.run(token)
```

Also it not write anything to the console if I send the message on a dc server.

There is no firewall rule what can cose the issue I olrady chacked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the bot intents are toggled in the [Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

If you had it enabled, you can try enabling all the intents and then putting this in the intents parameter

```py
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents().all())
```

The code will probably look like this

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents().all())

async def on_message(message): 
     if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
           print(message.content)
           await message.channel.send('Hello')

client.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a quick hint:
according to discords [API reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message) to the "on_message()" function you need to set Intents.messages to True.
In your case this would be

```
intents.messages = True
```

I did not test this code, but it's what I read from discords docs.
In the future you might want to have a look at it https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

I hope I could help you with this quick answer :)

Comment: I tryed to use this "intents.messages = True" but still not work. :(

Comment: Do you have any new error messages now ? Or is it the exact same as before ?